# Should your exceptions be named PrinterException or PrintingException

Tags: naming-conventions, class-design

Given an interface like

```
Printer {
  print()
}
```

should it throw PrinterException or PrintingException. I guess PrinterException is more generic in that it can also be used for methods done by the Printer that is not actually printing, say something like turnoff().

What if Printer actually had two methods

```
Printer {
   shutdown() throws PrinterShuttingDownException;
   print() throws PrintingException
}
```

or

```
Printer {
   shutdown() throws PrinterException;
   print() throws PrinterException;
}
```

Comment: Both are fine ,i think!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue PrinterException is better because it defines exceptions which aren't necessarily related to the act of printing, which is possible if the arguments aren't correct or it fails for a somewhat unrelated issue like problems logging to a file.

Though, it's subjective so it's up to you.

**Edit:**
If you have two operations, print and shutdown, then print should throw a PrintingException and shutdown should throw a PrinterShutdownException, both of which would derive from PrinterException.  This would allow you to catch specific cases or any exception related to the printer.

Comment: Yes it covers all exceptions thrown by a Printer, but would it be better to have a PrintingException and PrinterShutdownException it Printer had 2 methods - printer and shutdown

Answer (score 0):

I would always have PrinterException. It's an Exception, thrown by the Printer.

Comment: But it doesnt tell you must about what went wrong. Its not about who threw the exception but waht went wrong. You dont throw THingoException if something is null - one throws NullPointerException.